# Equality of a tangent and a cotangent

Tags: trigonometry

$\tan(-135^\circ)$ could be written as

> $\tan(-90^{\circ}+(-45^{\circ}))=\cot(-45^{\circ})=1,$

or

> $\tan(-135^{\circ}+180^{\circ})=\tan(45^{\circ})=1.$

Coming from this, other remaining trig functions that have arguments between $0\le\alpha\le360^\circ$ or $0\le\alpha\le-360^\circ$ (here $\alpha$s are arguments) can be written likewise (I think). But I am doubtful about the first expression: is it right to write trig functions with negative arguments not extending one full revolution without adding the smallest period and then evaluating since sometimes a function can change to its reciprocal as in my example above?

Comment: $cot (-45)=-1$ not 1 as you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

$$\tan(-90^{\circ}+(-45^{\circ}))=-\cot(-45^{\circ})=1$$ and
$$\tan(-135^{\circ}+180^{\circ})=\tan45^{\circ}=1,$$
which is right.

In the first we can use $\tan(-90^{\circ}+\alpha)=-\cot\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, $\tan(-135^\circ) \ne \cot(-45^\circ)$.

Your false equality (with degree symbols inserted) is this:

> $\tan(-90^\circ+(-45^\circ))=\cot(-45^\circ)$

The cofunction rule says $\tan(90^\circ - \theta) = \cot\theta$.  It is not true that $\tan(-90^\circ + \theta) = \cot\theta$.

However, you can use the fact that tangent is an odd function (so $\tan(-x) = -\tan x$) to do this:
\begin{align*}
  \tan(-135^\circ) &= \tan(-90^\circ - 45^\circ)\\
    &= \tan(-[90^\circ + 45^\circ])\\
    &= -\tan(90^\circ + 45^\circ)\\
    &= -\tan(90^\circ - [-45^\circ])\\
    &= -\cot(-45^\circ)\\
    &= -(-1)\\
    &= 1
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

All you need

$$\tan (180+a)=\tan (a) $$
$$\tan (-a)=-\tan (a) $$
$$\tan (90-a)=\cot (a) $$